# Query not ordering properly

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following query which I did not write to produce the results:

```
select distinct "ID","Name"
  from (
select myview.ID as "ID", myview.Name as "Name",
     rank() over (partition by myview.ID order by myview.OTHER_ID DESC, rownum) rnk 
from my_view myview
)where rnk = 1
ORDER BY "Name" DESC;
```

I need to order by the name attribute which is a string, but it is not ordering even though I have the order by name statement. How can I order it by name?

So for the `name` column the data it returns the data in this order:

```
 368838, "AUSER03232, JOHN"
 368532, "BUSER000417, JANE"
  20252, "BUSER108276, JANE"
  75235, "AUSER01809, JANE"
```

Comment: Since that looks reasonable, you need to show us some raw data, the output you get now, and the output you expect to see. The column data type and your NLS_SORT and NLS_COMP settings might be useful too, if it isn't just a misunderstanding about when the sort is applied for example. What is `rownum` doing in the rank clause - what is that supposed to be doing?

Comment: Those are ordered correctly.  Ascending would be A-Z, descending is Z-A.  `JOHN` comes before `JANE` descending.

Comment: And the order within duplicates is not deterministic as you haven't said what should happen - e.g. `ORDER BY "Name" DESC, "ID" DESC`. But as it isn't clear why you think it's wrong at the moment, not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: It is ordered correctly? Shouldn't AUSER01809, JANE be the second? This is the way I need it to be ordered.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. The data I provided is the value for the name, not the ID and NAME, just NAME. So the name column value is "AUSER01809, JANE"

Comment: Please show your actual data, actual query, and actual results. Giving inconsistent information is not helpful.

Comment: This is my exact actual data (portion since there are hundreds of thousands of records) and the results are real results from the first 4 rows. Everything in the query is right except the view name is actually year_cust_v and OTHER_ID is named 'pro_id'. I don't think the view and column names would actually make a difference though?

Comment: The output doesn't match the query, which is still confusing. Is later data ordered as expected? I'd guess you have invisible characters at the start of the ones that are out of order. Can you temporary modify your query to also return `dump("Name", 16)` and shwo that column in the output too?

Answer (score 0):

The `distinct` is not necessary (although it shouldn't affect the `order by`).  Your `rank()` includes `rownum` -- which should make each row unique.  Hence, just use `row_number()` instead and get rid of the `distinct`:

```
select "ID", "Name"
from (select myview.ID as "ID", myview.Name as "Name",
             row_number() over (partition by myview.ID order by myview.OTHER_ID DESC) as seqnum 
      from my_view myview
     ) v
where seqnum = 1
order by "Name" DESC;
```

This saves the overhead of the duplicate removal.

One thing that would cause your problem is if you used single quotes rather than double quotes in the `order by`:  `order by "Name"` is quite different from `order by 'Name'`.

Comment: The rownum is in the order by, not the partition, so it wouldn't make it any more unique; and would only have any impact if there was a duplicate ID,OTHER_ID pair? Even then its effect would be non-deterministic at best...

Comment: @AlexPoole . . . I'm pretty sure it is going to prevent duplicates in the `order by`, which -- in turn -- means that that the `rank()` will never return duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

Your output data isn't consistent with that query.

Using your "output" data .. and feeding it back into the query, and running results in a totally different output .. so there's something you're making up - I think.

Please, please PLEASE .. post a COMPLETE WORKING EXAMPLE .. from start to finish .. include table creation, or input data like I have ... run it yourself .. and show the actual results .. copy/pasted .. do NOT massage it manually to try to make it "look more like the problem".  If it doesn't re-create your "problem", then it's not a good example ;)

```
  with w_data as (
        select 368838 ID, 'AUSER03232, JOHN'  Name from dual union all
        select 368532 ID, 'BUSER000417, JANE' Name from dual union all
        select  20252 ID, 'BUSER108276, JANE' Name from dual union all
        select  75235 ID, 'AUSER01809, JANE'  Name from dual
        )
  select distinct ID, Name
    from (
        select myview.ID as ID, myview.Name as Name,
             rank() over (partition by myview.ID order by myview.ID DESC, rownum) rnk 
        from w_data myview
        ) 
  where rnk = 1
  ORDER BY Name DESC;

          ID NAME
  ---------- -----------------
       20252 BUSER108276, JANE
      368532 BUSER000417, JANE
      368838 AUSER03232, JOHN
       75235 AUSER01809, JANE

  SQL>
```

Note I have provided a query in which ANYONE can now copy/paste and run on their server, easily, and repeatably.  They can easily confirm if it generates the same results I have, or something different, and then easily tell what I did wrong (if anything) .. ;)